# How to get the api response to a variable from fetch call

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, fetch-api

I am trying to make an api call using fetch. But i am getting a promise in that not the data.If i resolve the promise inside fetch, i get the data not outside. How can i get the result from api to data variable.

```js
export function getAllBooks() {
    var data= fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/9paef').then((data) => {
        data.json().then(function (response) {
         return response
        });
    })
    console.log("data",data)
}
```

Comment: @Quentin This isn't an exact duplicate of the link you provided.We should open up this question.

Comment: @Ayan — Both questions are "How can I use a value generated inside a callback, outside the callback and before the callback has executed?". It is a duplicate. A dozen of these get asked every single day, and the duplicate has some very detailed and highly rated answers.

Comment: @Quentin This is more with fetch, and the provided link is more with ajax.I agree that the underlying logic is similar.But on an upper level they are a bit different.For beginners, this question can be helpful

Comment: There's no practical difference. The answers would be the same.

Comment: @Quentin , Yes the answer is similar but when i tried searching for this i didn't get any relevant answers. To get to the original questions that have already asked, i should have searched for "How do I return the response from an asynchronous call? " but this did not cross my mind. So people who are new to JS might find it useful.

Comment: @pKay — You seem to have missed the point of closing a question as a duplicate. Google will find this question, then people will get to this page, then they will see the big yellow box at the top of the page and see good answers.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for pointing out the original quesitons , it was very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `await` wich allows us to wait for the response of an asynchronous request. An example of use is here:

```
async function getAllBooks() {
  const response = await fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/9paef');
  const data = await response.json();
  //console.log('Data', data);
  return data;
}


getAllBooks().then((books) => {
  result = books;

  console.log("Books", result);
});
```

[See it on jsbin.com](https://jsbin.com/tinafanoqi/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: This is the type of vague description of async/await that leads to questions complaining that then they `return data` from `getAllBooks` the return value is a promise.

Comment: @Quentin The return value is not a promise. Please don't guess if you didn't ask the same question

Comment: https://jsbin.com/gifunuyafo/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I misunderstood your question! I will add more details then

Comment: There are some perfectly fine answers on the duplicate question.

Comment: Don't you mind to share? @Quentin

Comment: There's a link in the big yellow box at the top of the page. You can sort answers by votes.